# "damage" and "to do damage" in video games context

Tags: перевод, лексикон

I'm making a YouTube video game guide and I'm adding Russian subtitles to expand my audience. As you know, video games use phrases like "damage", "to do damage" and "deal damage," but I'm not sure which words and phrases to use:

- damage - вред or повреждение?
- to do/deal damage - вредить (что-нибудь) or давать вред/повреждение?

The game in question is Locoland/Steamland (*Дорога на Хон-ка-ду* in the original Russian), and "damage" in this context means in-game units losing hit points.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of game units losing hit points (especially if they are not individuals, but machines or formations), "damage" would be *урон* and "to deal damage" would be *нанести/наносить урон*.

That said, Russian is different from English, so  mechanically translating words and even phrases by substituting their dictionary forms just won't work.

For instance, the verb that translates "to deal (damage)" comes in two flavors — the so-called [aspects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) (I provided both of them), and without knowing the context, it's impossible to tell which one you should use.

If you don't want your game subtitles to end up a Russian version of "all your base are belong to us", you might want to find an actual translator for your game.

Comment: "наносить урон" sounds and looks ok in written language but in spoken speech it sounds a little but bulky. I cannot instantly come up with an easy to pronounce alternative. Perhaps "ранить" could work depending on the context.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: just to clarify, the units in that particular game are armored trains. I think the use of *ранить* when talking of damage done to military machinery is limited to the game of Battleships.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about gamer slang, the main words for "damage" and "to deal damage" are "дамаг" и "дамажить" which were adopted from English almost as is. Their official analogs used on official websites are "урон" and "наносить урон".

To the best of my knowledge, other words like "повреждение", "вред", and "ранение" never mean just "damage". They are usually used in more specific contexts, like "injury", "harm", and "wound".